# How to change the column label in screen options for a custom column?

Tags: plugin-development

I have added some columns to my custom post type listing tables using the following filters/actions:

- manage_*posttype*_posts_columns
- manage_*posttype*_posts_custom_column

This works fine and I have dispayed an icon in my table column's header. The columns also appear in the screen options dropdown but there the icon is also displayed with no text. How can I change what is displayed in the screen options area to display a text label - like comments - comments use an icon in the table but comments is written out in "screen options".

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Like here: https://imagebin.ca/v/2u2cuHeSGDE3

Comment: Could you please provide a short reproducible code example? It would be easier for others to look into, without having to build this from scratch.